# Select count paid order by user in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

If example I have this table

```
-----------------
|ID|user_no|paid|
|---------------|
|1 |1      |yes |
|2 |1      |yes |
|3 |1      |no  |
|4 |2      |yes |
|5 |2      |no  |
|---------------|
```

I want the result to be

```
-----------------------------
|ID|user_no|order_paid_count|
|---------------------------|
|1 |1      |2               |
|2 |1      |2               |
|3 |1      |2               |
|4 |2      |1               |
|5 |2      |1               |
|---------------------------|
```

I do the query like this, but it doesnt work.. it loading so long and didnt come out result, its like loop infinity

```
SELECT o1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order AS o2 WHERE o1.user_no=o2.user_no AND o2.paid=yes) as order_paid_count 
FROM order as o1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a sub-query that counts each user_no's number of paid orders. `LEFT JOIN` with that result:

```
select o1.id, o1.user_no, o2.order_paid_count
from order as o1
left join (select user_no, count(*) as order_paid_count
           from order
           where paid = 'yes'
           group by user_no) as o2
  on o1.user_no = o2.user_no
```

(`LEFT JOIN` to include also user_no's with no paid orders at all.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I try to get the o2 in select is really make me stressfull.. I didnt think that can use left join on it.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use DENSE_RANK method to achieve your result :

```
 SELECT ID , user_no , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY user_no DESC) 
        order_paid_count 
 FROM #Table 
 ORDER BY user_no
```

Comment: I never user DENSE_RANK before. is it will take query time shorter than join?